# Record with 'all' in database

Tags: database, checkbox, nested, record

I have the following hypothetical scenario:

A user can toggle aircraft categories wether he is interested or not.
If the user toggles `Helicoper` the following checkboxes with sub-categories will appear:

`'Chinook', 'Apache', 'Cargo', 'Military'`

to which the user can select from in form of checkboxes.

If the user toggles `Airplane` the following checkboxes with sub-categories will appear:

`'Passenger', 'Ultralight', 'Cessna', 'Cargo', 'Military'`

The following tables are designed to store the user's (id: 1) options:

#### aircraft_type

```
id | name   
1    Helicopter
2    Airplane
```

#### aircraft_class

```
id |  name   
1     Chinook
2     Apache
3     Ultralight
4     Cessna
5     Cargo
6     Military
```

#### aircraft_x_type_x_class

```
id | aircraft_id  |  aircraft_class_id
1         1                  1  
2         1                  2
3         1                  5
4         1                  6
5         2                  3
6         2                  4
7         2                  5
8         2                  6
```

#### user_x_aircraft_x_type_x_class

```
id | user_id | aircraft_x_class_id
1      1                1 
2      1                2
3      1                3
```

---

[image: visual representation of databse structure]

Now if I happen to have 1000 users who all selected every `aircraft_class` then the records pile up quickly.

To prevent (perhaps) unnecesseary records in my joint-tables I have thought of the following option at `aircraft_model` which is 'all'.

#### aircraft_class

```
id |  name 
....  
7     all
```

#### aircraft_x_type_x_class

```
id | aircraft_id  |  aircraft_class_id
....
 9         1                  7 
10         2                  7
```

So when a user selects every `aircraft_class` of a certain type, it will not create all the records, but instead just one that states 'all'

#### user_x_aircraft_x_type_x_class

```
id | user_id | Aircraft_x_class_id
1       1               9
```

### Question

Is this a common/good thing to do to reduce records at multi-level options? Are there perhaps better ways?